# Beginner Help Required - BottomNavBar

Tags: android, flutter, uinavigationbar, android-bottomappbar

I am just learning and can't wrap my head around something.

I am building a simple app but the app requires the first thing shown is a splash screen of some sorts.
Upon tapping the only button on the SplashScreen, ideally it would load the rest of the app however I also want my app inside to work around a bottomNavBar.

I have done the Bottom Navigation Bar on my own and it works so I can cycle between my pages, but my main.dart is pointing towards my Splash_Screen. Where as in the Nav model I am using, main points to the Nav.dart file.

How do I get my app to launch in this sequence: Splash_Screen --> when buttom tapped --> go inside where Bottom Navigation Bar will be leading to it's respective 3 pages.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: CODE

```
main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:offroad/screens/splash_screen.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

SplashScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:offroad/screens/home_screen.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  Color mainColor = Color(0xFFF1330A);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/splash.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black54,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 90,
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) => Home(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80),
                      height: 80,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: mainColor,
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Entrar',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 230,
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Text(
                    'Tu mundo 4x4\n empieza aqui!',
                    style: GoogleFonts.amiri(
                      height: 1.2,
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 40,
                      ),
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Once my splash page loads and the button is tapped I want it to now go inside and load this, which is what I had working seperately but with the main.dart pointing to the "nav.dart"

[image]

Comment: Please add the `flutter` tag so that relevant audience can help you and also provide the code so that it will be clear what the problem is !

Comment: thanks, I have added the code and an image to assist relaying the issue at hand. Thanks again!

Comment: can you be more specific about your question what you need ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly but you should use the routes or onGenerateRoute in MaterialApp to define your routes.
In that case you can get rid of the home and set the initial route to Splash Screen and the default as nav.
You can then navigate to your tab component using a named route defined in your routes or onGenerateRoute.